# How to process output of multiple tables from SQL procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, table-variable

I have a procedure that generates two tables as output, but it generates an error when I run it. I want to pass both tables to local variables.

```
DECLARE @model_data_stats TABLE (var VARCHAR(150), center FLOAT, scale FLOAT);
DECLARE @model_log_stats TABLE (var VARCHAR(150), zero INT, plusone INT, plustwo INT);
DECLARE @model_logit VARBINARY(MAX);

EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R',
     @script = N'
       #R script, irrelevant to question
       #the following variables are assigned:
       data_stats <- table
       log_stats <- table
       trained_model <- varbinary(max) data type
     ',
     @input_data_1 = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Table',
     @params = N'@data_stats TABLE (var VARCHAR(150), center FLOAT, scale FLOAT) OUTPUT,
                 @log_stats TABLE (var VARCHAR(150), zero INT, plusone INT, plustwo INT) OUTPUT,
                 @trained_model VARBINARY(MAX)',
     @data_stats = @model_data_stats OUTPUT,
     @log_stats = @model_log_stats OUTPUT,
     @trained_model = @model_logit OUTPUT;
```

This is the error I get when I run the code:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.
```

It's not even especially clear to me which occurance of `TABLE` generates the error, but my guess is the part where the output variables are defined (after `@params`). The `DECLARE` statements by themselves run just fine.

My guess is that I'm declaring the output of the procedure in a wrong way. I'm not sure what the correct way would be. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research I've found that what I'm trying to do here is impossible. From the [MS knowledge base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591996.aspx):

> In SQL Server 2016, the output of R from the stored procedure sp_execute_external_script is limited to a single data.frame or dataset. (This limitation might be removed in future.)
>
> However, you can return outputs of other types in addition to the dataset. For example, you might train a model using a single dataset as input, but return a table of statistics as the output, plus the trained model as an object.